# Inserting user updates into SQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql, insert

I think I am really close now - there are no more nasty Orange boxes with errors in - the only problem I can see at the moment is that once I update the table (after the

```
$qry = "UPDATE 'members' ('employer', 'flat') WHERE login='$login_name' VALUES ". " ('$employ', $address')";
```

) I get the message `"No rows updated"` echo to the screen!

Any ideas what the problem is?
Thanks.

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN'];
    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

//Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $employ = clean($_POST['employer']);
    $address = clean($_POST['flat']);



?>



<?Php
//Insert employer and address into database row for logged in user.    
$login_name = $_POST['login_name'] ;
$qry = "UPDATE 'members' ('employer', 'flat') WHERE login='$login_name' VALUES ". "     ('$employ', $address')" ;



    $result = @mysql_query($link, $qry);
    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if(!$result) {
        echo "No rows updated";
        exit();
    }else {
        echo "Success";
    }
?>
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future

Comment: Just to pre-empt the comments of depreciated mysql* functions, he is free to use whatever functions he wishes. Please don't post repeated comments.

Comment: @imulsion thank you! that's so annoying. who cares if he's using `mysql_`, it's entirely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Others have already said what's wrong. As a tip: output `mysql_error()` in the place of "No rows updated" to see what's going on.

Comment: I'm probably wrong but is the problem... How I have set $login_name as $_POST['login_name'] using echo var_dump($qry); is is showing that $login_name is set to $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN'] ... should this show as the actual login name that was used by the user when logging into the profile?    I hope I'm finally on the right track!!  Thanks for all your help and advice everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `VALUES`, use `SET`:

```
"UPDATE `members` SET `employer` = '".$employ."', `flat` = '".$address."' WHERE `login`='".$login_name."'"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just tried what you have entered imulsion but still has the same outcome!

Comment: @Tom36 hmm. Will edit answer with some other attempt to solve it :)

Comment: @Tom36 if you would debug like like Telmo Marques recommended, you'd already know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not suppress error messages by using the `@` opperator if you are looking for issues in your code. Also you are using the wrong parentheses (**'** instead of **`**). The rest of your code looks fine. maybe you need to give us some info about the database structure otherwise

Comment: database is `code` member_id, firstname, lastname, login, passwd, age, employer, flat `code`  still not shiwng any errors

Comment: the names alone won't help. First try to remove he `@` and use basic debug (like `var_dump()` combined with `exit;` after every important step). If that doesn't help tell us how your database table is designe. I mean like fieldtype and so on.

Comment: I believe so:    $result = @mysql_query($link, $qry);
 //Check whether the query was successful or not
 if(!$result) {
  echo mysql_error();
  exit();
 }else {
  echo "Success";
 }
?>

Comment: remove the `@` and use `var_dump` instead of `echo`. That should give you the information you need.

Comment: $result = mysql_query($link, $qry);
 //Check whether the query was successful or not
 if(!$result) {
  var_dump mysql_error($result);
  exit();
 }else {
  echo "Success";
 }
?>

Comment: with or without $result in the mysql_error the screen is either blank or ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING. I have also removed the @

Comment: It is not our job to find every single minor error in your code. The error message is quite clear. There should also be a line number where to find the typo. Otherwise ask google. There are plenty results for `unexpected T_STRING`